# Connect() function in C, invalid argument

Tags: c, sockets, client-server

I'm coding a client/server, the client simply sends a message to the server that he will print the message.

To do this I used sockets and localhost. Here is the code:

server:

```
    #include <unistd.h> 
    #include <stdio.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h> 
    #include <stdlib.h> 
    #include <netinet/in.h> 
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/un.h> 
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include"thpool.h"
    #include"functions.h"
    #define N 7
    #define SERVER_PATH "/tmp/server"

    int main(void){
        unlink(SERVER_PATH);
        struct sockaddr_un stru;
        int sock_serv, new_sock;
        int opt = 1;
        struct sockaddr* cliaddr;
        char buff[N];

        cliaddr = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr));
        socklen_t addrlen = strlen((char* )cliaddr);

        if((sock_serv = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
            printf("socket creation error");
            exit(-1);
        }

        bzero(&stru, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)); 

        stru.sun_family = AF_UNIX ;
        strncpy (stru.sun_path, SERVER_PATH, sizeof(stru.sun_path));

        if((bind(sock_serv, (struct sockaddr*) &stru , sizeof(struct sockaddr_un ))) < 0){
            perror("bind failed"); 
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }

        if(listen(sock_serv, SOMAXCONN) < 0){
            perror("listen error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }

        if((new_sock = accept(sock_serv, NULL, 0)) < 0){
            perror("accept error\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
        }

        read(new_sock , buff, N) ;
        printf("Server got: %s\n" , buff);

        close(sock_serv);
        close(new_sock);

        unlink(SERVER_PATH);
        return 0;
    }
```

and here is the client:

```
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include"thpool.h"
#include"functions.h"
#define SERVER_PATH "/tmp/server"

int  main(void){

    int sock_cl;

    struct sockaddr* sa;
    socklen_t sa_lenght;
    sa = malloc(sizeof(struct sockaddr));
    sa_lenght = strlen((char* )sa);

    if((sock_cl = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket creation error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    sa->sa_family = AF_UNIX ;
    strncpy (sa->sa_data, SERVER_PATH, sizeof(sa->sa_data));

    while (connect(sock_cl , (struct sockaddr*)&sa , (socklen_t)sa_lenght) == -1) {
        perror("connection to the server failed");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);             
    }

    write (sock_cl, "Hello!", 7);
    printf("message sended\n");
    close(sock_cl);

    return 0;
}
```

I have a problem with the connect() function, the error is "invalid argument". Note that I first executed the server and then the client, so is not that the problem.

Comment: Why do you need a while loop in the client file when you call exit() and abort in the loop?

Comment: You malloc a buffer for the sockaddr, but you don't put anything there, so strlen() is undefined, looking at rendom bytes. Even if you had put something there, it's a structure, not a string, so why do you think strlen() will be useful for anything? The sockaddr structure is supposed to be filled in by you with an address.

Comment: Aside: The `lenght` typo is really irritating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you define sa, as a pointer to struct sockaddr.

```
struct sockaddr* sa;
```

Here you take the address of the variable `sa` and cast it to the type of sa.

```
(struct sockaddr*)&sa
```

The result is a pointer to pointer to struct sockaddr, which gets brute force cast to pointer to struct sockaddr.

Type-casting is a trap and you got caught in it.

To solve, I recommend using a tutorial on sockets.
I think that when comparing your client and the example client in this tutorial especially the pointer level issue you have created becomes nicely visible:
https://www.cs.rpi.edu/~moorthy/Courses/os98/Pgms/socket.html

Comment: That's why the error. He also needs to actually put something in the sockaddr structure.

Answer (score 0):

Your server and client are both misusing the `sockaddr...` structures. The error on the server side doesn't affect anything because it is not actually using the faulty `sockaddr` it allocates, it just leaks.  But your client is completely misusing the `sockaddr` that is passed to `connect()`, which is why `connect()` fails.

Try this instead:

server

```c
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include "thpool.h"
#include "functions.h"

#define N 7
#define SERVER_PATH "/tmp/server"

int main(void){
    unlink(SERVER_PATH);

    struct sockaddr_un stru;
    int sock_serv, new_sock;
    ssize_t bufflen;
    char buff[N];

    if((sock_serv = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        printf("socket creation error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    bzero(&stru, sizeof(stru));
    stru.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy (stru.sun_path, SERVER_PATH, sizeof(stru.sun_path));

    if((bind(sock_serv, (struct sockaddr*) &stru, sizeof(stru))) < 0){
        perror("bind error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    if(listen(sock_serv, SOMAXCONN) < 0){
        perror("listen error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    if((new_sock = accept(sock_serv, NULL, 0)) < 0){
        perror("accept error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    bufflen = read(new_sock, buff, N);
    if (bufflen < 0) {
        perror("read error");
    }
    else if (bufflen == 0) {
        printf("Client disconnected\n");
    }
    else {
        printf("Server got: %.*s\n", (int) bufflen, buff);
    }

    close(new_sock);
    close(sock_serv);

    unlink(SERVER_PATH);
    return 0;
}
```

client

```c
#include <unistd.h> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <netinet/in.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "thpool.h"
#include "functions.h"

#define SERVER_PATH "/tmp/server"
const char *msg = "Hello!";

int main(void){

    int sock_cl;
    struct sockaddr_un sa;
    ssize_t sent;

    if((sock_cl = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket creation error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
    }

    bzero(&s, sizeof(sa));
    sa.sa_family = AF_UNIX;
    strncpy (sa.sa_data, SERVER_PATH, sizeof(sa.sa_data));

    if (connect(sock_cl, (struct sockaddr*) &sa, (socklen_t) sizeof(sa)) < 0) {
        perror("connect error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);             
    }

    sent = write(sock_cl, msg, strlen(msg)+1);
    if (sent < 0) {
        perror("write error");
    }
    else {
        printf("Message sent: %.*s\n", (int) sent, msg);
    }

    close(sock_cl);
    return 0;
}
```